# page not showing in Vuejs project

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a project with Vue.js, I have no familiarity with it but I'm trying to figure out how it works.

My problem, for now, is this:
I'd like to create a new page, defining its route and a static template to be rendered inside, just to see a "new page" for now, but the template I have created is not rendered (and no error is given).

Actually I have `app/router/routes.js` file with this part added:

```
{
    path: 'blocked-segments',
    name: 'blocked.segments',
    component: require('pages/BlockedSegments').default
  }
```

This is working because actually I can "see" the route, but nothing has been rendered in the page.
Here is the `pages/BockedSegment.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <div class="blocked-segments">
    BLOCKED SEGMENTS
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'blocked.segments'
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Very simple, static, nothing weird but nothing happens. I mean, I can see the browser pointing at the right route, but the HTML of the page is like this:

```
<body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>Javascript is disabled...</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I need to understand what I'm doing wrong... maybe I'm ignoring something very basic.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE 1:
This is the `App.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="w-full h-full">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>
```

Comment: Show us your `app.js`

Comment: Ok, I found the Error, in the "path" property of the router, I missed the "/" that goes in the beginning. I wrote  path: 'blocked-segments', but should be  path: '/blocked-segments',